# Quadratic equations in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to solve $x^2-4=0$ but results should be written in form $a+bi$.

$z=\pm 2$ that means that results are $2+i0$ and $2-i0$ or what?

Comment: rather $2+0i$ and $-2+0i$ but yes

Comment: Oh, $\mathbb C$, not the C programming language :-)

Comment: The results $2, -2$ are already complex numbers for $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $0i = 0$ on top of that $a+0=a$ in every field.

Answer (score 0):

When we write:$$z=a+ib$$$a$ represents the **real** component and $b$ represents the **imaginary** component.

In your case, both answers are **real** so they can be written as:$$z=\pm2+0i$$

But, as @alvin pointed out in the comments above, $0i=0$ and therefore it is valid to write the answer as:$$z=\pm2$$

Compare this to some ficticious problem where the result was $\pm2i$, this could be written as:$$z=0\pm2i$$But is usually written as:$$z=\pm2i$$